# Си: При вызове return меняется значение переменной, адрес которой возвращает функция

Tags: c, return

Простите, вопрос уже задавали - я не нашел
История:
Пишу программу по работе с ДДП, АВЛ-деревом и хэш-таблицей. И есть такая структура:

```
struct AVL
{
    int value;
    unsigned char height;
    AVL *left, *right;
};
```

В таком виде все работает
Однако, если я меняю местами поля вот так:  `

```
struct AVL
{
    AVL *left, *right;
    int value;
    unsigned char height;
};
```

Или использую #pragma pack:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct AVL
{
    int value;
    unsigned char height;
    AVL *left, *right;
};

#pragma pack(pop)
```

То программа ломается.
Я отследил в дебагере проблемное место, оно в функции создания АВЛ-дерева на основе ДДП:

```
void bst_to_avl(BST *tree, AVL **root)
{
    if (tree && root)
    {
        *root = avl_add(*root, tree->value);
        bst_to_avl(tree->left, root);
        bst_to_avl(tree->right, root);
    }
}
```

Вот состояние в проблемной функции до вызова avl_add:
[image: До вызова]
В функции avl_add создается правильная вершина: 
[image: Внутри avl_add]
Но, после выхода из функции по return, оно портится и превращается в это:
[image: После вызова]

Естественно, дальше программа работает неправильно.
И мне не понятно несколько вещей - как это исправить (если я из принципа хочу именно такой порядок полей)
И из-за чего это вообще возникает?
Возможно, где-то я допустил очень глупую ошибку и теперь просто не вижу её
Если нужно, могу выложить сюда весь проект, но там много файлов
Содержимое BST.h

```
#ifndef _BST_H_
#define _BST_H_
typedef struct BST BST;

struct BST
{
    BST *left, *right;
    int value;
};

BST *bst_add(BST *root, int num);
void bst_free(BST *root);
int count_peaks(BST *root);
#endif
```

[Ссылка на исходники](https://yadi.sk/d/Ew5OlJgws6a1kQ)

Comment: Вы, по-видимому, что-то недоговариваете... Наличие `baadf001` в памяти - скорее всего не случайность и как бы намекает, то между этими двумя точками произошло что-то еще.

Comment: А попробуйте распечатать, скажем, `printf("%zu\n", offsetof(AVL, right))` внутри `avl_add` и внутри `bst_to_avl`. Эти значения совпадают?

Comment: Чесслово, есть return и то, что после, все на скринах. Могу видео записать :)

Comment: @AnT, bst_to_avl: 16, avl_add: 8

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно использовал '@'. Я тут новенький, как правильно?

Comment: Это все компилируется одновременно или что-то компилируется отдельно, как библиотека?

Comment: Все собирается вместе (утилита make), без библиотек, сначала собираются объектники, потом из них exe

Comment: Тогда хорошо было бы взглянуть на 1. параметры командной строки компилятора для обоих `.c` файлов, 2. полный текст заголовочного файла, 3. содержимое обоих `.c` файлов до включения этого заголовочного файла.

Comment: В частности, а не играется ли `BST.h` с настройками выравнивания и упаковки? И если играется, то возвращает ли он их потом "на место"? Подозреваю, что именно в этом дело.

Comment: @AnT, Я прикрепил ссылку на исходники, тк выкладывать их сюда не удобно

Comment: @Rabter, у тебя `Makefile` кривой: `*.o` файлы не зависят от всего, что включают `*.c`... отсюда и проблемы, что при изменении `AVL.h` перебирается только `AVL.o` и `main.o`... `make clean` в помощь....

Comment: @Fat-Zer, это вероятно не все, у него размер структуры разный в разных участках кода при выполнении.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Информация, предоставленная вам в комментариях (величина `offsetof(AVL, right)` отличается в разных единицах трансляции), говорит о том, что у вас разные единицы трансляции используют *разные* определения структуры `struct AVL`. Возможно, что "текст" этого определения используется один и тот же, но, например, установки выравнивания и/или упаковки данных - разные в разных единицах трансляции. Из этого вытекает и наблюдаемое вам поведение.

---

Я попробовал ваш код - все прекрасно работает. Однако ваш `makefile` не строит полных зависимостей исходников от заголовочных файлов. То есть при изменении `AVL.h` автоматически перестраивается только `AVL.c`, но не остальные исходники, которые зависят от `AVL.h`. В этом, по-видимому, и заключается ваша проблема: вы меняете определение `struct AVL`, но потом под новое определение перестраиваете только `AVL.c`.

При таком `makefile` вам обязательно нужно делать `make clean` после каждого изменения `.h` файла и перестраивать все заново с нуля.

А в общем, в "настоящих" мейкфайлах обычно выполняется построение файлов зависимостей `.d` при помощи ключей компилятора группы `-M`. Такие `.d` файлы затем включаются в `makefile`. Именно благодаря им любые изменения в `.h` файлах приводят к перекомпиляции всех `.c` файлов, которые от них зависят.

В вашем случае один из простейших вариантов решения проблемы:

1. Добавить ключ `-MMD` в командную строку компилятора
2. Включить `.d` файлы в `makefile`
3. Удалять `.d` файлы в `clean`

   ```
   CC := gcc
   CFLAGS := -std=c99 -Wall -Werror
   DEPFLAGS := -MMD

   ifeq ($(mode), debug)
       CFLAGS += -g3
   endif

   -include *.d

   %.o: %.c %.h
       $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

   app.exe: main.o io.o BST.o AVL.o bst_to_avl.o arrgen.o hash_table.o search.o restruct.o
       $(CC) $^ -o $@

   clean:
       rm *.o *.d *.exe
   ```

Такой вариант подразумевает, что никто не будет удалять `.d` файлы отдельно от `.o` файлов.

Comment: И как это исправить? Интересно, почему такое вообще возможно, но что делать в случае, когда возникает такая неприятность? Только поля переставлять?

Comment: @Rabter: Не, конечно. Разбирайтесь, как и почему такое произошло. и устраняйте разницу. По тому, что вы пока привели, трудно что-то сказать. Вы вообще уверены, что у вас в программе только одно определение `struct AVL`?

Comment: Есть идеи, из-за чего такое может случиться? Вроде оба используют один и тот же хедер... Я-то поищу в любом случае, конечно, но если есть соображения - это поможет

Comment: Настройки компилятора для каждого файла реализации могут задаваться отдельно. Из-за их различия запросто может получиться такой рассинхрон, даже если используется один и тот же хедер. Для начала надо зафиксировать вариант `struct AVL`, с которым мы работаем. А то у вас в вопросе два или три варианта, а на скриншотах - еще один, не совпадающий ни с одним из вопроса.

Comment: Тогда возьмем структуру без #pragma pack, в которой первыми полями указываются адреса right и left (кстати, если разнести это объявление на две строки, то ничего не меняется) Остальное, вроде, и так все время одинаковое. Так в каком направлении копать, говорите?

Comment: Значения `offsetof`, которые вы предоставили (8 и 16), они относятся именно к этому варианту? Скорее всего нет. Перепроверьте именно в этом варианте: чему равно `offsetof(AVL, right)` в двух местах. Внутри `avl_add` и снаружи.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `pack(push, 4)` и если собираете gcc то лучше перейти на тег `__attribute__`

Comment: Ради теста можете попробовать описать битовые поля,если заработает, надо глядеть тонкие настройки оптимизации компилятора, `int value:4; unsigned char height:1; AVL *left:4, *right:4;`

Comment: @AnT, Я чесслово не знаю что сделал, но теперь оно работает, если указатели идут первыми, и не работает, если они последние. И в таком виде выводит bst_to_avl: 8
avl_add: 16 (то етсь еще и эти поменялись местами). Не понимаю, что произошло, не знал, что я настолько не квалифицирован..

Comment: @Rabter: В каком "таком" виде 8 и 16? "Первыми" или "посередине"?

Comment: @AnT, в том виде, в котором сейчас работать перестало. Это когда оба поля в структуре объявлены последними

Comment: "Работает" и "работать перестало" - это не важно и не интересно. Еще раз:  8 и 16 - это для какого варианта структуры? И посмотрите на вторую часть моего ответа. Что там у вас в `BST.h`?

Comment: @NewView, простое использование pragma pack(push,4) не помогло. Чуть позже попробую битовые поля

Comment: @AnT, в BST.h pragma не используется. Полное содержимое сейчас прикреплю к самому вопросу
8 и 16 (теперь) для варинта, когда оба поля последние: "Это когда оба поля в структуре объявлены последними ". P.S:Ранее это было когда оба поля были в начале (причем 8 и 16 всегда выводится в том варианте, в котором она не работает)

Comment: Там в чем то ином проблема, если шевеление кода влияет на результат и нет прямой зависимости.

Comment: @Rabter: См. третью часть моего ответа.

Comment: Господи, какая глупая ошибка... Спасибо болльшое

Comment: @AnT, отдельная цель для `main` не нужна, а первой целью лучше поставить `app.exe` или добавить `all`.